# Is async.each non-blocking? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I want to make non-blocking loop over array with objects, so I used *async.each* function:

```
log.info("before");

async.each(products , function(prdt, callback){
    for(var i = 0 ; i <4000000000; i++){
        var s = i;
    }
    console.log("inside");
    callback();

}, function (err) {
    console.log("end");
});
log.info("after");
```

So if  I run code above I have a such messages output:

```
before
inside
....
inside
end
after
```

If async.each asynchoronous why I dont see output in that order?

```
before 
after
inside 
inside..
end
```

**UPDATE1:**
thx for answers, but If I want to execute that code inside my router, I will blocked all responces to my server? What I need to change?

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/4101af3f402008ea82c8de38ec3bd852aa3d7565/lib/async.js#L230

Comment: "What I need to change?" --- a programming language. JS (its userland, to be precise) runs in a single thread.

Comment: so, how I can itearate over array asynchronously and dont block  user responces to my server?

Comment: You cannot. JS is single threaded. So whenever you run this CPU-bound code everything else will wait.

Comment: So no matter what I use  simple 'products.forEach' or async.each? When I iterate over array I block my whole server?

Comment: JS is single threaded. Which means at any given moment only one execution context is active.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack: Yes, your server is blocked - but that hardly matters, because you're not doing much for each request, and your server can easily handle thousands of normal loops. You will need to change that `for(var i = 0 ; i <4000000000; i++)` thing to something more efficient, or to something that is asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi but what is the whole idea behind `async.each` though? Why not use a normal `Array.prototype.forEach` instead?

Comment: @zerkms: To handle loops where the item-callback does something asynchronous. It's a helper library for working *with* asynchronous code, not to make anything asynchronous by itself.

Comment: @Bergi I see now. So it makes sense to use it if only you have a 3rd parameter passed. Otherwise it's a simple `[].forEach`

Comment: Big thx for help guys, I too much scare to block my whole server, thats my first node.js steps , so I was just a little confuse. Now I understand all that "async" features

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack: Don't be scared. JS is fast enough, all normal control structures and even loops over normal-sized data are totally fine and done in a matter of less than milliseconds. Where you need to avoid "blocking" is whenever you want to wait for something - a user input, a timeout, a file system read, a network request, a socket read. But all those things are inherently asynchronous already, i.e. not blocking, in their API. You hardly can do anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the `async.each` function is simply implying that it can be used for asynchronous actions because it inherently includes a callback function (which is trivial for you to add yourself in your own function).

Consider this code which uses Mongoose (a MongoDB wrapper) to simulate a real-world asynchronous call:

```
console.log("before");

async.each(["red", "green", "blue"], function(color, cb) {

    mongoose.model('products')
        .find({color: color})
        .exec(function(err, products) {
            if (err) return cb(err); // will call our cb() function with an error.
            console.log("inside");
            cb(null, products);
        });

}, function(err, products) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log("really after");
    console.log(products);
});

console.log("after");
```

You'll get

```
before
after
inside
really after
[red products]
inside
really after
[green products]
inside
really after
[blue products]
```

Does it make sense why? Let me know if I can break any of this down further.

Comment: Yep, you give me what I want to see.

Answer (score 0):

async.each() is asynchronous, but you're not doing anything that is blocking or requires an asynchronous loop.  If you put a setTimeout() in there you'd see it working like you expect.

Comment: "async.each() is asynchronous" --- what does this exactly mean? I provided a link to the source which states that it runs a callback synchronously

Comment: "If you put a setTimeout() in there you'd see it working like you expect." --- what is the point in using `async.each` if you still need `setTimeout()`?

Comment: `setTimeout()` is simply an example of code that triggers an asynchronous event. That is, a `setTimeout()` inside a function inherently means some code will run in a future event loop, even through the function that wraps the `setTimeout()` call will return immediately.